# insert from table to another with additional columns PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm using PHP to insert data from a table to another that has an additional column, then delete the row from the first table. But, I cannot seem to make it work:

```
public function insertReq($dID, $bphone)
    {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO RequestedDevices(dID, deviceName, Medical, Description, Educational, DevicePicture, bphone) VALUES((SELECT id, deviceName, Medical, Description, Educational, DevicePicture WHERE id = ?), ?)");
           $stmt->bind_param("ss", $dID, $bphone);
            $flag = $stmt->execute();
            $stmt1 = $this->conn->prepare("DELETE FROM DEVICE WHERE id= ? ");
            $stmt1->bind_param("s", $dID);
            $flag1 = $stmt1->execute();
            if ($flag & flag1) {
                return ADDED;
            } else {
                return NOT_ADDED;

            }

        }
```

Comment: For one thing, you're using a bitwise here `($flag & flag1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the additional column as a constant in your select, and you do not need the VALUE() around the select. :

```
public function insertReq($dID, $bphone)
{
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO RequestedDevices(dID, deviceName, Medical, Description, Educational, DevicePicture, bphone) SELECT id, deviceName, Medical, Description, Educational, DevicePicture, ? WHERE id = ? from TABLE NAME )");
        $flag = $stmt->execute(["someAdditionalColumData", "someID"]);
        $stmt1 = $this->conn->prepare("DELETE FROM DEVICE WHERE id= ? ");
        $flag1 = $stmt1->execute(["originalTableID"]);
        if ($flag & flag1) {
            return ADDED;
        } else {
            return NOT_ADDED;
        }
    }
```